# What Java SDK can I use to return a list of devices in an IoT hub

Tags: java, azure-iot-hub

Unlike the C# SDK, I am unable to find any Java SDKs that lists IoT devices in an IoT hub. Please can anyone help?

Comment: I think you mean a library. And the question appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: @Frederico Colluoca, rules are to be violated.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Microsoft provides an IoT client class library : [iot-service-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot/iot-service-client)

You can check the whole article related how to list the IoT devices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-device-management-getstarted).

Comment: Thanks. Classes DeviceTwin, SqlQuery, and DeviceTwinDevice do the job. Problem sorted.

Comment: Please mark as answer if the above response helped.